# How to drop marker at lat/long in new Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

How would one go about dropping a marker at a certain lat/long in the new Google Maps?

Visiting https://www.google.com/maps/@37.7,-122.4,16z only centers the map at those coordinates but does not drop a marker.

Edit: discovered a solution:

https://www.google.com/maps/place//@37.7,-122.4,16z/

Comment: If you found the way to resolve your problem you should answer your question with the explanation.

Comment: "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 3/21/2014 3:45:43 AM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Comment: You should have sufficient reputation to post an answer now - I just upvoted your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

https://www.google.com/maps/place//@37.7,-122.4,16z/

This also works:

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=37.7,-122.4

Comment: This is a hack that only kind of works. If you for example zoom in till you get the street view, then out again, the marker disappears. Likewise if you navitage away (with the browser to another web page) then back, the marker isn't there (as google has added junk to the url).
Still, much better than nothing! (: